# Weird pagination behavior in CListView in Yii

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I'm a Yii and php newbie, I'm trying to make a page based on the default index page (with CListView) generated by Yii tutorial website. The gii generated my model and CRUD w/ controllers and index page has almost 100 pages, and all I want to do is:

**to add a textfield and a button to specify a condition to the result by 'controller/index' view.**

E.g. I want to add a filter 'year' so I added a form just above the CListView:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'fromid')); ?>
   <?php echo CHtml::textField('year');?>
   <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('search',array('submit'=>'index.php?r=mycontroller/index')); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

So that by clicking the button it will have a submit action w/ textfield value from id 'year' posted. And I catch the action in controller like this: (in mycontroller)

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if(isset($_POST['year']))
    {
        $y = (int)$_POST['year'];
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Model',array('criteria'=>array('condition'=>'date='.$y);
        $this->render('index',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
    }
    else
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Model');
        $this->render('index',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
    }

}
```

The code above just works fine. I entered a year and clicked button, the age refreshed and result filtered. But the problem is, **if the result is being paginated into several pages (like 2 pages), and I click the next page button, the filtered result is gone!**, the result went back to the 100 pages again. I'm really out of idea how this is happening.

the Clistview is very simple here I didn't add any extra property:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using $_POST, the `$_POST['year']` data is lost when you're navigating to the next page, since you're not posting it to page 2, 3 etc.

You can do two things:

- Store the `$_POST['year']` in a session, so the next page 'knows' what year it has to use
- Store it in the url as a $_GET parameter, so instead of `$_POST['year']` use `$_GET['year']`. When you navigate to page 2, the `$_GET['year']` is available in the url on the next page.

The last one is the easiest one i think, and that's how i usually use it.

IF you use the get method, change the CActiveForm line to this:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
         'id'=>'fromid',
         'method' => 'get'
)); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! So I just simply replace '$_POST' with '$_GET'? Is it that easy?

Comment: Yes and change the 'method' in your CActiveForm to 'get', that will do it (see my edit). And please consider to use bounded parameters instead of `$date='.$y` it's much safer!

Comment: I still need a little help here: I changed my code to using GET parameter, it works great! except that everytime I click search the parameter keep appending in the url make the url longer and longer. -_-!!